# How to set the specific prefix for file-loader in webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I have sass file with font:

```sccs
$icons-font-path: "~material-design-icons/iconfont/";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(#{$icons-font-path}/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

And file-loader that downloads the font to a specific directory (`/home/user/project/example/src/static/fonts/`):

```js
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
    loader: 'file',
    query: {
      name: path.join(STATIC_PATH, 'fonts', '/[name]-[hash].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

It's work fine for me, but out css has same path in `url`, like:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(/home/user/project/example/src/static/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

How do I copy `woff2` to a specific directory and set specific prefix for `url(prefix/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**resolve-url-loader**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) will allow you to specify your font `url()` relative to your `.sass` file. The `.css` should have a path url that Webpack can resolve to a module.

The key thing is for Webpack to locate all of your assets that you specified in `url()` statements. At that point **resolve-url-loader** is job done. The `absolute` option should never be needed, as you should always setup Webpack to find all your "modules", including assets.

By default (and I am not an expert on Webpack) all the css and assets are coppied to the output and the correct relative paths are rewritten to the css `url()` statements.

I am thinking that the crux of your problem is similar to a CDN deployment, where you want some absolute prefix. If this is the case then look to the [public path](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) property. I have not used it myself but it appears to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably gonna want to use some combination of the [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) and the [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader).

Your webpack loader config will look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test   : /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveUrlLoader: {
      absolute: '/prefix'
  }
};
```

Comment: `absolute: 'prefix'` prefixes `'prefix'` to the absolute url. is there a way to prefix it to the relative url?